# How to check if two variables are dependent given a third variable?

Tags: r, correlation, data-visualization, independence, partial-correlation

In `R`, I have a dataset of many variables and based on correlation matrix I see that some of the variable are correlate with the others. For simplicity, let's assume that there are three variables $X, Y, Z$ that have high pairwise correlation coefficients. But it seems that information about the variable $Y$ is already included in the variable $Z$. How can I check (in R or in Python) if $X$ is dependent on $Y$ given $Z$?

Comment: You might have a look at partial correlations http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation e.g. implemented in R package 'ppcor'.

Comment: For a descriptive analysis, you could look at conditional plots, in `R` that is `coplot`. Example in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203494/can-i-analyze-or-model-a-conditional-correlation/368228#368228